# Sniper rifle chest piece

Tags: modeling

This is a sniper rifle chest piece which has a cylindrical type thing attached to it

[image: this is a sniper rifle chest piece which has a cylindrical type thing attached to it]

I have tried many ways but having no idea how to make it like this[image]

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post an image](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: You can upload and share your blend file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Actually it is a sniper gun i have modelled whole gun this is the reference image but i am facing problem while modelling the end piece. And having no idea how to model it

Comment: What kind of modelling are you using ? Could you share a wireframe view of that part of your gun model ?

Comment: I basically use poly modelling